# Drawing a Circle in the Complex Plane from a Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Secondary student here (or 9th Grade), so sorry if I find it hard to understand, as we have not been taught this and probably won't for a few years to come.

I have come across a question where I have been given the polynomial $z^4-6z^3+24z^2-18z+63$ where $z^2 + 3 = 0$ is a known root. Therefore I found the roots to be $\pm i\sqrt{3}$ and after factorisation $3 \pm 2i\sqrt{3}$.

I gave this a brief sketch on the complex plane, but how would I find the exact equation of this circle?

Sorry if this question is a common one, I couldn't seem to find out how anywhere, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which circle are you talking about?

Comment: I think he is a talking about the circle centered in $(3,0)$ with radius $r= 2\sqrt{3}$. (in the complex plane)

Comment: Supposedly, with the information I've found I should be able to find the equation of the circle on the complex plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this sketch will give you more ideas.
You can try to find a complex $z =a+i \,b$ such as for all your roots $r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4$ :

$|z-r_1| =|z-r_2| = |z-r_3| = |z-r_4|$

[image]

I don't know if it helps you. If you succeed to do so then the center of the circle will be $(a,b)$ and the radius $R = |z-r_1|.$

Comment: So the equation would be $\ x^2 +y^2-6x+9\ $ - I can get that with the help that you gave me, but I'm trying to figure out how you got it in the first place.

Comment: If $z$ is as described then you have $|z-i\sqrt{3}| = |z+i\sqrt{3}|$ so $|z-i \sqrt{3}|^2 = |z+i\sqrt{3}|^2$ thus $|a+i(b-\sqrt{3})|^2 = |a+i(b+\sqrt{3})|^2$ so you end up with : $ a^2+(b-\sqrt{3})^2 = a^2 + (b+\sqrt{3})^2 $ it implies (by expanding and simplyfing) that $4\sqrt{3} b =0$. Thus, you have necessarily $b=0$. It is geometrically clear, that if you look for an equidistant point of C and D, it is located on the x-axis. Therefore $z=a$ and you need to find what can be $a$.

Comment: You know that $|z-(3+2i\sqrt{3})| = |z-(-i\sqrt{3})|$ so $|a-3+2i\sqrt{3}|^2 = |a+i\sqrt{3}|^2$ so $(a-3)^2 +4 \times 3 = a^2 + 3$ thus $a^2-6a+9+12 = a^2 +3$ therefore $6a = 18$ so $a=3$. And necessarily $z=3$, you finally check that all the points are equidistant to (3,0). And $|z-i\sqrt{3}| = \sqrt{z^2+3} =\sqrt{12} = 2\sqrt{3}$ (it is your radius)

Comment: Excuse me if this is wrong, but from my understanding of your explanation $\ z = 3 +2i \sqrt{3} \ $ and therefore (a,b) = (3, 2√3) but this isn't the centre of the circle.

Comment: Therefore the equation of your circle is given by : $(x-3)^2+(y-0)^2 = r^2 = 12$ thus $x^2-6x+9 +y^2 =12$ so $\boxed{x^2+y^2-6x-3 = 0}$

Comment: I solved simultaneously $ \ (-a)^2 + 3 = r^2 ; (3-a)^2 + 12 = r^2 \ $ and I got that result too. I'm sorry I'm just finding this a bit confusing.

Comment: What do you find confusing? I didn't say I had the best approach, I just suggested you one way to do it.

Comment: No I have written $z=a+ib$ and then I deduced $b$ that was $0$ and then $a$ that was $3$, so $z=3$.

Comment: No, you're being a great help. It's just that I'm having to learn these concepts without a teacher. What I'm finding confusing is mainly the translation between my roots and your equations that you've given.

Comment: Ok, do you know that $|a+i b| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$?

Comment: And how did you deduce this?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. The lines are the modulus (only positive outcome) right?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: You said you wanted a circle to match your roots, so you know if there is a circle that goes through all your roots, then the center of that circle is equidistant to all the points representing the roots in the complex plane. If $z=a+i b$ then the point that corresponds to $z$ is $(a,b)$.

Comment: Okay, I understand about the equal distance from the centre, but I'm not sure what you mean about corresponding.

Comment: English is not my mother tongue so sorry if there is a confusion, but I mean if you have a complex, let's say $3+4i$ and you want to put it in the complex plane, then you draw the point $(x,y) = (3,4)$.

Comment: Yes, I understand that as in the i in the plane is the y axis. If you prefer to speak some French, I can try understand as I study it, but won't understand the mathematical terms, but you speak very good English anyway.

Comment: No I won't speak French, it will be too confusing for you. Thank you, I just don't write a lot of mathematics in English, so maybe the vocabulary is not always perfectly accurate. Yes that's right, if you look at my diagram, you have : $A$ that represents $3+2i\sqrt{3}$, $C$ representing $i \sqrt{3}$, and so on.

Comment: Yep, understood.

Comment: Do you still have any other questions? Don't hesitate.

Comment: Sorry if this will be time consuming, but I would really appreciate if you could go through your method step by step, and point out your reasoning for it. Don't feel obliged to, though.

Comment: I don't have much time. But I am going to try again in 15min.

Comment: Okay sure, take all the time you need.

Comment: First, you have found all your roots, you draw them in the complex plane naming them respectively $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$, $A_4$, you are looking for a circle intersect all your points. If there exists a point that is equisdistant from all your points, then there must be a circle centered at this point going through all your points, right?

Comment: Do you mean there is a smaller circle around this point, or that it's the centre?

Comment: I mean it is the center.

Comment: Okay, and the distance from that to our point would be the radius.

Comment: Yes exactly, that's it. Let's call this point $M$, then $A_1M = A_2M = A_3M = A_4 M$ is the radius.

Comment: So the only information we have at hand right now is the equation of our points?

Comment: No, it is the coordinates of our points.

Comment: Then we will make the following hypothesis : point $M$ exists - represented by complex $z = a + i b$

Comment: If such $z$ exists, what can I say about it?

Comment: No, $z$ is for the center

Comment: Okay so would we have to add our respective co-ordinates?

Comment: Let's say $r_1 = \sqrt{3}$, $r_2 = -\sqrt{3}$, $r_3 = 3 + 2\sqrt{3}$, $r_4 = 3-2\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: You don't know anything about the center, you just assumed it exists. So for the moment $z = a+ib$ can be anywhere in the plane

Comment: Then like $M$ is equidistant to the other points you have $|z-r_1| =|z-r_2| = |z-r_3| = |z-r_4|$

Comment: Okay, and this therefore represents the distance to the centre, and therefore the radius?

Comment: Yes yes, and you use this equality to determine $a$ and $b$ as I did above.

Comment: How would you do this?

Comment: Oh sorry, I haven't seen your message. You just solve as I did in my first message :-)